# confusion about the boundry map in the cone construction

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm self studying algebraic topology from Rotman's book and I've encountered the following on pages 72--74.

Choose a point $b\in X$. For every $n$-simplex $\sigma\colon \Delta^n\to X$ we define an $(n+1)$-simplex $b\cdot \sigma\colon \Delta^{n+1}\to X$ by

$
b\cdot \sigma(t_0, t_1, \dots, t_{n+1})=
\begin{cases}
b & \text{ if } t_0=1\\
t_0b+(1-t_0)\sigma\left( \frac{t_1}{1-t_0}, \dots, \frac{t_{n+1}}{1-t_0}\right)
&\text{ if } t_0\ne 1
\end{cases}
$

When $n=0$ we can identify $\sigma$ with its image $x\in X$. Then $b\cdot \sigma\colon \Delta^1\to X$ is $(b\cdot \sigma)(t)=tb+(1-t)x.$

Rotman writes $\partial(b\cdot \sigma)=b-x$ but I think it should be $x-b$ because $(b\cdot \sigma)(0, t_0)=x$. Could someone clarify please?

**Edit**
Here is some additional set of definitions/notations that I need to make the question self contained:

If $\sigma\colon \Delta^n\to X$ is continuous and $n>0$, then its boundary is

$\partial_n\sigma=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\sigma\epsilon_i^n\in S_{n-1}(X)$
where $S_k$ denotes the free abelian group with basis all singular $k$-simplexes in $X$. Also the $i$th face map $\epsilon_i^n\colon \Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^n$ is

$\epsilon_0^n\colon (t_0, \dots, t_{n-1})\mapsto (0, t_0, \dots, t_{n-1}),\quad
\epsilon_i^n\colon (t_0, \dots, t_{n-1})\mapsto (t_0, \dots, t_{i-1}, 0, t_i, \dots, t_{n-1}) \quad \text{ if } i\ge 1.$

If $n=0$, define $\partial_0\sigma=0$.

Comment: When you write "$(b \cdot \sigma)(0,t_0)$", are you thinking of $n=1$ or of feeding the interval $(0,t_0)$ to $b \cdot \sigma$?  If the latter, $b \cdot \sigma$ is not constant on any open interval of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$  (b \cdot \sigma)(t) = t b + (1+t)x  \text{,}  $$
a point tracing the line segment from $x$ (at $t=0$) to $b$ (at $t=1$).  So, "$\text{last} - \text{first}$" is $b-x$.

(One way to remember this is the right order is to read it a little differently.  "$b-x$" is "get a $b$ while losing an $x$", which is what happens when you move along $b \cdot \sigma$.)

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Initially the choice $b-x$ was more natural to me than $x-b$ because of the parametrization of the line segment and the "last-first" intuition. But what if we use the definition of the boundary (that now I've added to the question)? Shouldn't $\partial_1b\cdot \sigma=b\cdot \sigma \epsilon_0-b\cdot \sigma\epsilon_1$? If yes, am I right to say that $b\cdot \sigma\epsilon_0(t_0)=b\cdot\sigma (0, t_0)=x$? (I'm sorry if this is too obvious. I've had only a little sleep and just don't seem to be able tot get my head around this at the moment.)

Comment: This is addressed in the errata for this text.  See http://www.orecoli.com/entry/2016/05/27/183219 -- the signs are backwards, so it should be $b-x$.

Comment: @Simon : I might recommend Munkres's or Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.  (... with their errata in hand).  Actually, I would recommend both, together.  Munkres dives into the details and Hatcher stays out of the weeds.

Comment: Thanks for the link! (so I was right about $x-b$. I suspected this, but couldn't find it in an errata that I had.) Would you mind telling me why you prefer Munkres's book over Rotman's? I learned point-set topology from Munkres years ago and it was nice as a book for self study; but now that I'm more experienced I wish it had emphasized some topics that are useful in other areas (e.g. nets, Zariski topology, etc) to give a bigger picture.

Comment: ... I was hoping I can learn some standard material from Rotman and then consult Prasolov's book(s) (Elements of combinatorial and differential topology, and Elements of homology) but maybe I need to switch from Rotman to Munkres if I'm convinced that would be a better choice for me.

Comment: @Simon : I also learned point-set from Munkres many years ago.  I don't think Munkres's algebraic topology is as well suited for self-study; Hatcher's is.  But then Munkres fills in many details.  You may find Munkres's algebraic topology is styled more as you now wish his point-set had been.  Of course, your mileage may vary.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't understand what the errata is saying.  Is it saying that $x_i - b$ is incorrect?  Because following along with Simon's proof I get his same result and don't see how the definition of $\partial$ returns $b - x_i$.

Comment: @OliverG : This erratum clearly states to replace "$b - x_1$" and "$(\dots)b - \gamma$" respectively with "$x_i - b$" and "$\gamma - (\dots)b$", so the erratum states that "$x_i - b$" is correct.  You should check the definition of the boundary homomorphism: the sum index tells you which endpoint is *omitted*.

Comment: @EricTowers The question Simon asked originates from a step in the proof of a theorem that states for $X$ convex and $\gamma = \sum m_i \sigma_i$  and $n = 0$ we have $\partial (b. \gamma) =  (\sum m_i)b - \gamma$ and $\gamma - b. \partial \gamma$ if $n \gt 0$.  So should the theorem be $\gamma - b. \partial \gamma$ for all $n$?

Comment: @OliverG : The statement in the theorem is reversed for $n = 0$ case.  Since the theorem only proves the $n = 0$ case, the erratum must only apply to that case.  However, your most recent line "$\gamma - b . \partial \gamma$" is gibberish when $n = 0$.  There's nothing left to take a boundary of so the result cannot try to take boundary.